# phpMyAdmin access denied

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

I am using wamp server, and my phpMyAdmin page returned the following error.

> Wamp server version:2.2     MySQL version:5.5.24
>
> #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I edited my config file,  **wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14\config.inc.php** to:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

But it did not solve the problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Bt default the `username = root` and the `password = nothing(leave it blank)`

Comment: When you say _I edit wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14\config.inc.php_ **what did you change??**

Comment: Do you get the Username / Password prompt, or does it attempt to log in without entering a Username or Password?

Comment: Verify that you are using right credentials(set password if its there), if its not works still, you may show your connection code so some can identify issue if its in code

Comment: If you dont communicate with us, people will get bored and go and do something else. and this question will be forgotten about

Comment: PS: The current version of WAMPServer is version **3.0.4** you are a bit behind the curve

Comment: I solved the problem. When I entered password blank and restarting all services, phpMyAdmin page is working.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this in your   phpmyadmin config.inc.php  :-

```
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.